Average on Average SQL
I want to know how we do this formula on SQL
Name    Category    Value
A   1   3
A   2   4
A   1   5
A   2   2
A   1   3
A   2   1
B   1   2
B   2   3
B   1   4
B   2   5
B   1   6
B   2   7
B   1   5

Average
A   3
B   4.625

Example, there are 2 Name A & B, Each Group have 1,2,3,... division, Each division have value

First step: Average Value by Division (it might be have more than 1 value)
Second step: Average Value by Group (Division1,Division2,......)
Third step: Average Value by Name (Group1,Group2,....)

Formula with Excel:
AVERAGE((SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,1,B:B,"A")/COUNTIFS(B:B,"A",C:C,1)),(SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,2,B:B,"A")/COUNTIFS(B:B,"A",C:C,2)))

Any help will be appreciated.

Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

As per details try with following step.

Average Value by Division:

SELECT Name, Division, AVG(Value) AS AverageValueByDivision
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Name, Division;


Average Value by Group:

SELECT Name, AVG(AverageValueByDivision) AS AverageValueByGroup
FROM (
    SELECT Name, Division, AVG(Value) AS AverageValueByDivision
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Name, Division
) AS DivisionAverages
GROUP BY Name;


Average Value by Name:

SELECT AVG(AverageValueByGroup) AS AverageValueByName
FROM (
    SELECT Name, AVG(AverageValueByDivision) AS AverageValueByGroup
    FROM (
        SELECT Name, Division, AVG(Value) AS AverageValueByDivision
        FROM YourTable
        GROUP BY Name, Division
    ) AS DivisionAverages
    GROUP BY Name
) AS GroupAverages;


AVG(AverageValueByDivision) is nonsense as it's an average of averages, you probably want SUM(TotalValue) / SUM(CountOfValues)
